# Export catalog_tables from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, catalog, export

I have installed fresh Magento and have backup old public_html files.But I forget export products from Magento admin. How can I export catalog tables from myphpadmin section ?

I still backup old database.

Also import to new database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to install a magento again with that old database and export your products.

There are many tables involved in saving products, categories and all relations. Also if you don't have the same Magento Version in both instances there may be differences in the database structure

Comment: As you recommend I'd installed fresh magento to old database but no have any products or catalog.I am using same version.Do you have any idea?
Also I was selected file system session on installation page.

Comment: thats weird. you have entries in the catalog_product_entity table?

Comment: I import catalog_product_entity table but I don't know how to entries.Also I setting local.xml file

Comment: so you set up a new magento instance and edited the local.xml to point at your old database? you should have your old page again with all products (without images if you did not copy the media dir)